# remember last view position of html in Firefox

Tags: firefox-extensions

I have a novel in html format and I would like to read it in Firefox. But every time I open it, it begins at the beginning instead of when I left last time. Are there any plugin to help me automatically scroll to where I read last time?

P.S. I found a plugin Session Manager, it can restore the closed session and back to the exactly point where I read. If it is okay after further testing, will post it as answer after 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the restore web pages everytime you open firefox option in the option pane?? I'm not sure whether it will pop you to the same location, but i'm pretty sure it will land you to same page every time you open it!

[image]